# clearsceeen and equal functions not working responsive in my calculator code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

    def btnClick(numbers):
    global operator
    operator=operator + str(numbers)
    text_input.set(operator)

def btnClearDisplay():
    global operator
    operator=""
    text_input.set=("")

def btnEqualsInput():
    global operator
    sumup=str(eval(operator))
    text_input.set(operator)
    operator=""

cal = Tk()
cal.title("Calculator")
operator = ""
text_input = StringVar()


txtDisplay = Entry(cal,font=("Helvetica", 15, 'italic'), 
textvariable=text_input, bd=18, insertwidth=4,
                           bg="grey", justify='right') .grid(columnspan=4)

btn7=Button(cal,padx=12,bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial',15,'bold'),
            text='7',command=lambda:btnClick(7), bg="silver") 
.grid(row=1,column=0)

btn8=Button(cal,padx=12,bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial',15,'bold'),
            text='8',command=lambda:btnClick(8), bg="silver") 
.grid(row=1,column=1)

btn9=Button(cal,padx=12,bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial',15,'bold'),
            text='9',command=lambda:btnClick(9), bg="silver") 
.grid(row=1,column=2)

addition=Button(cal,padx=12,bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial',15,'bold'),
            text='+', bg="maroon",command=lambda:btnClick("+")) 
.grid(row=1,column=3)

btn4=Button(cal, padx=12,bd=8,fg="black",font=("arial", 15, 'bold'),
            text='4',command=lambda:btnClick(4), bg="lightblue") 
.grid(row=2,column=0) 

btn5=Button(cal, padx=12,bd=8,fg="black",font=("arial", 15, 'bold'),
            text='5',command=lambda:btnClick(5), bg="lightblue") 
.grid(row=2,column=1) 

btn6=Button(cal, padx=12,bd=8,fg="black",font=("arial", 15, 'bold'),
            text='6',command=lambda:btnClick(6), bg="lightblue") 
.grid(row=2,column=2) 

subraction=Button(cal, padx=12,bd=8,fg="black",font=("arial", 15, 'bold'),
            text='-',command=lambda:btnClick("-"), bg="lightblue") 
.grid(row=2,column=3) 

btn1=Button(cal, padx=12,bd=8,fg="black",font=("arial", 15, 'bold'),
            text='1',command=lambda:btnClick(1), bg="lightblue") 
.grid(row=3,column=0) 

btn2=Button(cal, padx=12,bd=8,fg="black",font=("arial", 15, 'bold'),
            text='2',command=lambda:btnClick(2), bg="lightblue") 
.grid(row=3,column=1) 

btn3=Button(cal, padx=12,bd=8,fg="black",font=("arial", 15, 'bold'),
            text='3',command=lambda:btnClick(3), bg="lightblue") 
.grid(row=3,column=2) 

multiplication=Button(cal, padx=12,bd=8,fg="black",font=("arial", 15, 'bold'),
            text='*',command=lambda:btnClick("*"), bg="lightblue") .grid(row=3,column=3) 

btn0=Button(cal, padx=12,pady=12,bd=8, fg="black",font=("arial", 15, 'bold'),
            text='0',command=lambda:btnClick(0), bg="lightblue") .grid(row=4,column=0) 

btnClear=Button(cal, padx=12,pady=12,bd=8, fg="black",font=("arial", 15, 'bold'),
            text='C', bg="lightblue", command=btnClearDisplay) .grid(row=4,column=1) 

equals=Button(cal, padx=12,pady=12,bd=8, fg="black",font=("arial", 15, 'bold'),
            text='=', bg="lightblue", command=btnEqualsInput) .grid(row=4,column=2) 

divide=Button(cal, padx=12,pady=12,bd=8, fg="black",font=("arial", 15, 'bold'),
            text='/', bg="lightblue", command=lambda:btnClick("/")) .grid(row=4,column=3) 


cal.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome. Just saying "Not working" and "not responsive" and then posting a wall of code is not a good question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. For example, if the problem is with a "clear" button, we don't need all of the other buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that you're not calling the `set` method properly.  Consider this code:

```
text_input.set=("")
```

Notice the `=`, which means you are destroying the `set` method and replacing it with an empty string. Instead,  you need to call the `set` method like this:

```
text_input.set("")
```

Answer (score 0):

And for the = button.

Your code:

```
def btnEqualsInput():
    global operator
    sumup=str(eval(operator))
    text_input.set(operator)
    operator=""
```

LAGGY FIX, needs double click, i don't know why.

```
def btnEqualsInput():
    global operator
    sumup=str(eval(operator))
    text_input.set(operator)
    operator=sumup
```

completely fixed:

```
def btnEqualsInput():
    global operator
    sumup=str(eval(operator))
    operator=sumup
    text_input.set(operator)
```